# how to set custom message for specific field

Tags: jsf, properties, message

Hi using JSF 1 (not JSF 2).

```
<h:inputText id="myElem"
         value="#{backingBean.myElem}"
         required="true"/>
<h:message id="myElemMsg" styleClass="errorMsg" for="myElem"/>

<h:inputText id="myElem2"
         value="#{backingBean.myElem2}"
         required="true"/>
<h:message id="myElem2Msg" styleClass="errorMsg" for="myElem2"/>
```

My message properties is:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=A value is required.
```

Now the I get A value is required whenever anything is missing, however i want a custom message for myElem2 to say something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you're using JSF 1.0/1.1. You've then basically 2 options:

1. Create a custom validator.

   ```
   <h:inputText id="myElem2" 
       value="#{backingBean.myElem2}"
       validator="customRequiredValidator" />
   ```

   Wherein you just throw a `ValidatorException` with therein the desired message.

   ```
   if (isEmpty(value)) {
       throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Your message here"));
   }
   ```
2. Or, simply upgrade to JSF 1.2. It introduces the `requiredMessage` attribute.

   ```
   <h:inputText id="myElem2" 
       value="#{backingBean.myElem2}"
       required="true" requiredMessage="Your message here" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `requiredMessage` attribute of `h:inputText`.

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/inputText.html

I guess this is a duplicate question :)

Comment: thanks not possible as i might be using version older than that